# variable value is changing autoamatically

Tags: c++

After taking the input for variable k,its value is automatically changing to 5.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int search(int arr[], int target, int size) {
    int l = 0; int mid;
    while(l <= size) {
        mid = l + (size-l) / 2;
        if(arr[mid] == target) 
            return 1;
        if(arr[mid] > target)
            size = mid - 1;
        if(arr[mid] < target)
            l = mid + 1;
    }
    return 0;       
}

int sort(int arr[], int size) {
    int temp; bool swap = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        bool swap = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < size - i; j++) {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                temp = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }

        if(swap == false)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n, k; 
    int count; 
    int j;
    int arr[n];

    cin >> n;
    cin >> k;
    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        cin >> arr[i];
    sort(arr, n - 1);              
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        value=arr[i] + k;
        j = search(arr, value, n - 1);
        if(j == 1)
            count++;         
    }
    cout << count;    
}
```

I printed the value of k just after the input and it shows the correct value. but inside the main function when i am using it to calculate the variable "value" its value is being taken as 5.Something is happening before the sort function is being called.

Comment: 1) `int arr[n];` is non-standard C++, due to being VLA. 2) Since `n` contains indeterminate value - `int arr[n];` is undefined behavior, even in compilers, which enable VLAs.

Comment: Please consider [cleaning up your code formatting](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Comment: You didn't initialize `count`

Comment: You have uninitialized variables causing undefined behavior which means anything can happen, including changing the value of another unrelated variable.